# "position" property required for ItemList with Product list items?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I have a problem: Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool gives me an error:

> Tag `position` doesn't exist. It's required.
>
> [image: Tag position doesn't exist]

I add it to the markup. Than I get this error:

> `Position` property is not valid for an object of type `Product`
>
> [image: Position property is not valid for an object of type Product]

Here is my markup:

```html
<table id="sale_table" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
    <tbody>
            <tr itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                <td class="sale_art_td" itemprop="productID">10496278</td>
                <td class="sale_brand_td" itemprop="brand"><span itemprop="name ">--</span></td>
                <td class="sale_name_td" itemprop="name">10496278 / Крышка трамблера Daewoo Nexia,Espero DD</td>
                <td class="sale_am_td">1.00</td>
                <td class="sale_price_td" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUR"><span itemprop="price">341.50</span></td>
                <td class="sale_buy_td"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sale_buy_link" data-id="63455914" data-query="10496278">Купить</a><!--<img src="/upload/badge/sale_cart.png" />--></td>
                <td class="hidden">
                    <meta itemprop="url" content="/partsearch/?q=10496278">
                                        <span itemprop="description">Распродажа: 10496278 / Крышка трамблера Daewoo Nexia,Espero DD по цене 341.50</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
                    <tr itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                <td class="sale_art_td" itemprop="productID">76202sx0a12</td>
                <td class="sale_brand_td" itemprop="brand"><span itemprop="name ">HONDA</span></td>
                <td class="sale_name_td" itemprop="name">76202SX0A12</td>
                <td class="sale_am_td">1.00</td>
                <td class="sale_price_td" itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"><meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUR"><span itemprop="price">704.00</span></td>
                <td class="sale_buy_td"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sale_buy_link" data-id="63456060" data-query="76202sx0a12">Купить</a><!--<img src="/upload/badge/sale_cart.png" />--></td>
                <td class="hidden">
                    <meta itemprop="url" content="/partsearch/?q=76202sx0a12">
                                        <span itemprop="description">Распродажа: 76202SX0A12 по цене 704.00</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: It's a been a year and we still don't know what it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not an error with your code. It just means that Google won’t display a certain Rich Snippet (or a similar feature) unless you provide this property.

However, the [`position` property](http://schema.org/position) is not defined for the [`Product` type](http://schema.org/Product), so this does not make any sense.

It seems that this is a new structured data feature from Google, which is not documented yet, as it links to a 404 page: [List Page Carousels](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/carousels/list-pages). Maybe it’s a work in progress and they didn’t mean to publish the check in their Testing Tool yet.

So I’d simply ignore this for now.

Comment: Word "required", that's what confuses me =)

Answer (score 5):

From my testing malefique is onto the right solution.

This code fully validates using the [Structured Data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/):

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "ItemList",
    "itemListOrder": "http://schema.org/ItemListOrderDescending",
    "itemListElement": [
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
                "@type": "Product",
                "name": "My product",
                "url": "www.example.com",
                "offers": {
                    "@type": "Offer",
                    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
                    "price": "100.00",
                    "priceCurrency": "AUD"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: do you know if Google actually implements this structure of LD+JSON when it finds it in your page? I suspect it may be too far from what Googlebot is expecting.

Comment: Except as far as I (mis?)understand after reading some decent amount of contradictory information on the subject, it's discouraged to have products and/or offers on a category page (https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/carousel#summary)

Answer (score 4):

I guess this is an implementation error on Google's side caused by non explicit documentation:

https://schema.org/itemListElement clearly states

> Existing entities are best for a simple, unordered list of existing things in your data. **ListItem is used with ordered lists** when you want to provide additional context about the element in that list or when the same item might be in different places in different lists.
>
> Note: The order of elements in your mark-up is not sufficient for indicating the order or elements. **Use ListItem with a 'position' property in such cases.**

At the same time is says *Values expected to be one of these types* are:

- ListItem
- Text
- Thing

=> This means **implicitly**, that the *position* element can only be required for sorted lists, which in turn demand that the Thing element is contained inside a *ListItem* element, which offers the itemprop *position*.

It also means **implicitly** that if the *ItemListElement* is *Text* or *Thing*, the list should be considered *Unordered*.

This is the only way the documentation makes sense. I assume that implicit connection was missed.

So I guess the appropriate action is to file a bug report for the *Structured Data Testing Tool* and live with the warnings for now **or** nest the *Product* inside a *ListItem* element as a workaround.

Comment: I tried the workaround myself, but it does not seem to work:

  - If I nest the Product inside a ListItem element, WMT complains about the wrong object Type
- If I use _Thing_ it complains _The property xyz is not recognized by Google for an object of type Thing_.
- Same happens if I try _additionalType: http://schema.org/Product_ with either the _ListItem_ or the _Thing_ element.

==> I can not find a valid encoding for a _Product_ list.

Comment: I have the same issue. But not sure if its a bug in the testing tool or something else. If it is a bug then will google ever fix it ? I can see this post is more than a year old, but still the bug is there.

Comment: 2019 and its still not fixed

Comment: I'm using an array of `SportEvent` in my `ItemList` which also has no position prop so nothing else to do really

Answer (score 2):

I found http://schema.org/itemListElement

you have to specify the position like so `<meta itemprop="position" content="1" />`

There is an example at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
'@type': 'ListItem',
'position': 1,
'item':{
   '@type': 'Product',
... product props
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix is to stuff your `product` into a `ListItem`'s `item` property. The `ListItem` gets the `position` property. Once you do that, it passes Google's SDTT.

NOTE: It is invalid to have a product `offer` on more than 1 URL/URI.

Build out a page (unique URL) for each product offer and that's where you put your structured data / schema.org product offer data; OR, put all your product offers on a single page (URL/URI) - never both. Otherwise, you'll get error `All values provided for url must point to the same page.`